# how to create Multiple choice google form from spreadsheet

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I would like to create a MCQ from an existing spreadsheet that has this type of data :

```
Question    Choice 1 (correct answer)   Choice 2    Choice 3    Choice 4
Question 1  a                            b                 c    d
Question 2  d                            a                 b    c
Question 3  b                            a                 b    c
```

Thank you for your answer Chris, but this code :

```
function createForm(){
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow());
var values = range.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
   .setTitle(values[i][1])
   .setChoiceValues([values[i][2],values[i][3],values[i][4]]); //Make another loop here if your Answers counts are different
}
}
```

displays unfilled questions, something like this :
[Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arn5A.png)
But what I would like to create should look like this at the end :
[Form2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUzWt.png)

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

```
 var form = FormApp.create('New Form');

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow());
 var values = range.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
       .setTitle(values[i][1])
       .setChoiceValues([values[i][2],values[i][3],values[i][4]]); //Make another loop here if your Answers counts are different
}
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I have found the solution :

Answer (score 0):

Here what i have came out as a soultion :

```
    function createForm(){
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow());
var values = range.getValues();

 var ansRange1 = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow());
 var ansValues1 = ansRange1.getValues();

var ansRange2 = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow());
var ansValues2 = ansRange2.getValues();

var ansRange3 = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow());
var ansValues3 = ansRange3.getValues();

var ansRange4 = sheet.getRange(2, 5, sheet.getLastRow());
var ansValues4 = ansRange4.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < (values.length)-1; i++) {
   form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
   .setTitle(values[i])
   .setChoiceValues([ansValues1[i],ansValues2[i],ansValues3[i],  ansValues4[i] ]); //Make another loop here if your Answers counts are different
}
}
```

But I'm still strugling how to make a correct answer and to give a number of point to the correct answer : without having to these two steps manually from forms.
So if someone can help me figure that out he is more than welcome!